# Execute just one SQL file via Flyway

Tags: java, flyway

I have multiple SQL files in my 'resources/sql/create' folder. I just want to run one SQL file via Flyway. But the following doesn't work:

```
final Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(jdbcUrl, "", "");
flyway.setLocations("classpath:sql/create/create_table_person.sql");
flyway.clean();
flyway.migrate();
```

How do I execute just one SQL file? I can't remove the other files since they are inside a test-jar file.

Comment: I don't think you can do it via `locations` since Flyway scans the location as an entry directory for migration scripts. Maybe you can use `sqlMigrationPrefix` property to distinguish the test and prod scripts by the filename.

Comment: Thanks @TomasTulka! In my case I used `sqlMigrationSuffix` and it works.

Comment: What is the reason you're trying to exclude the other files?

Comment: @DavidAtkinson Because I'm using a test-jar that contains all SQL scripts used normally to create all tables. But in my test case, I only need one table.

Comment: If the other objects are already in the target and were put there by Rlyway, the scripts won’t be run by Flyway anyway.

Comment: What I'm working on is a junit test by the way. The table is created on `setup` and deleted on `teardown`.

Comment: Interesting. Why do you feel the need to create just the table for the test? Can't you create all objects, and run the tests on this? Why add and remove schema objects?

Comment: And why do you think I need to create all the tables for just a test on one table? Also, do you think I should run junit test cases against an external database and not an embedded one, so I can retain the schema objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly request to migrate to a certain version using the target parameter. For example, using CLI:

```
flyway migrate -target=1.2.3
```

Using Java lib it should be:

```
flyway.setTargetAsString("1.2.3");
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, several of my SQL scripts have the same version `1.0.0.4` with my script `V__1_0_0004__create_table_person.sql`, and I'm not able to rename them.